# Sentence in a single SELECT

Tags: sql

I have two tables in a database. One is called `sec_users` and has three fields:

```
pk_user, name, dias_disponibles
```

And another that is called `solicitud` and has three fields:

```
pk_solicitud, fk_empleado, n_diassolicitados
```

Each user has for example 24 days available of vacation and can create vacation requests, those vacations can also be low, absences or permits. Well my problem is that to make the report I make a query to the database and the query does me very well, I get the full report but this query I want to do with a single SELECT, some help ??

I leave here my query:

```
SELECT u.name, u.dias_disponibles,
       (u.dias_disponibles - COALESCE(dias_disfrutados,0)) AS dias_libres,
       COALESCE(dias_disfrutados,0) as dias_disfrutados,
       COALESCE(dias_baja,0) as dias_baja,
       COALESCE(ausencias,0) as dias_ausencias,
       COALESCE(permisos,0) as dias_permisos,
       COALESCE(rechazadas,0) as solicitud_rechazadas
FROM (SELECT u.*,
             (SELECT SUM(N_DIASSOLICITADOS)
              FROM solicitud s
              WHERE s.fk_empleado = u.pk_user and s.fk_estado <> 2 and (s.fk_motivo = 1 OR s.fk_motivo = 2 OR s.fk_motivo = 3)
             ) as dias_disfrutados,
             (SELECT SUM(N_DIASSOLICITADOS) 
                FROM solicitud s
                WHERE s.fk_empleado = u.pk_user and FK_MOTIVO = 4) as dias_baja,
             (SELECT SUM(N_DIASSOLICITADOS) 
                FROM solicitud s
                WHERE s.fk_empleado = u.pk_user and FK_MOTIVO = 3) as ausencias,
             (SELECT SUM(N_DIASSOLICITADOS) 
                FROM solicitud s
                WHERE s.fk_empleado = u.pk_user and FK_MOTIVO = 5) as permisos,
             (SELECT COUNT(FK_ESTADO) FROM solicitud s WHERE s.fk_empleado = u.pk_user and FK_ESTADO = 2) as rechazadas
      FROM sec_users u 
     ) u
```

I JUST WANT IT WITH A SELECT AND I DO NOT KNOW HOW TO DO IT!

The result should be like that, but with only one SELECT:

```
Usuario           dias_disponibles dias_libres dias_disfrutados
==============    ================ =========== ================
Usuario 1                24             10            14
```

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text, not images.

Comment: This is your 4th question on this (albeit under a different [user name](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9390912/alvaro-roman-franco)). Every time you've been asked to post sample data, why don't you?

Comment: Yes, there you have the sample data that should come out, they come out like this, I only want the sentence in a single SELECT

Comment: We want the data you start with, the expected result alone is not very helpful. Also, what do you mean with "I want to do with a single SELECT"? In your previous questions you've also been asked about your dbms, which we still don't know. And finally, please don't SHOUT.

Comment: User1 has 24 `dias_disponibles` and if you request a 14-day request, you have 10 `dias_libres`.

Comment: @HoneyBadger Ok with that data?

Comment: No, please read [mcve]. Provide data preferably as inserts (include create scripts of the tables), so we can copy paste in our own test environments. Add a handful of rows of data per table, in your case ideally for two or more `Usuario`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use case when instead of several subselect

```
SELECT u.name, u.dias_disponibles,
       (u.dias_disponibles - COALESCE(dias_disfrutados,0)) AS dias_libres,
       COALESCE(dias_disfrutados,0) as dias_disfrutados,
       COALESCE(dias_baja,0) as dias_baja,
       COALESCE(ausencias,0) as dias_ausencias,
       COALESCE(permisos,0) as dias_permisos,
       COALESCE(rechazadas,0) as solicitud_rechazadas
FROM (

     select u.name, u.dias_disponibles
          , sum( case when s.fk_estado <> 2 
                and (s.fk_motivo = 1 
                        OR s.fk_motivo = 2 
                        OR s.fk_motivo = 3) 
                then  N_DIASSOLICITADOS else 0 end ) as dias_disfrutados
          , sum( case when  FK_MOTIVO = 4
                then N_DIASSOLICITADOS else 0 end )  as dias_baja
          , sum( case when  FK_MOTIVO = 3
                then N_DIASSOLICITADOS else 0 end )  as ausencias
          , sum( case when  FK_MOTIVO = 5
                then N_DIASSOLICITADOS else 0 end )  as permisos 
          , sum( when  FK_ESTADO = 2
                then 1 else 0 end) s rechazadas

      FROM sec_users u 
      inner join solicitud s on s.fk_empleado = u.pk_user
      group by u.name, u.dias_disponibles ) u
```

and if the user have not ever mathc use left join

```
      ......
      FROM sec_users u 
      left join solicitud s on s.fk_empleado = u.pk_user
      ......
```

Comment: There is no other way by removing the SELECT u. * ??

Comment: you  need  u.name, u.dias_disponibles in external select  so asnwer update for only the twa columns

Comment: @HoneyBadger   .,. correct .. answer  updated  with group by  .. many thanks

Comment: This function is fine but if I create a user for example user2 and user2 has not created any request, it does not appear in the table

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for